# WPF Binding to a DependencyProperty problem with an custom User Control inside a Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I need some help. I created a custom User Control, and inserted it into the Main Window. However, Im not able to bind a Property in the Window to a DependencyProperty in the User Control.

Here's the User Control code.
XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeExample.UCFullName"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeExample"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Content="First Name :" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <TextBox Name="FirstName" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,2,0,0" MaxLength="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TextChanged="TxtBlock_TextChanged"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Content="Last Name :" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <TextBox Name="LastName" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,2,0,0" MaxLength="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" TextChanged="TxtBlock_TextChanged"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

And here's the code behind

```
    using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SomeExample
{
    public partial class UCFullName : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void Notify(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged implementation


        public string ValueFullName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ValueFullNameProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ValueFullNameProperty, value);
                Notify("ValueFullName");
            }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueFullNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ValueFullName", typeof(string), typeof(UCFullName), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));


        public UCFullName()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TxtBlock_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ValueFullName = FirstName.Text + " " + LastName.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image: User Control]

And here's the code of the Main Window:

```
<Window x:Class="SomeExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeExample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Some Example" Height="200" Width="400">
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical" Name="SpManual" Background="Black">
    <GroupBox Header="Name" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" Name="groupBoxCoordinateStart" >
        <local:UCFullName ValueFullName="{Binding Path = PropertyFullName, Mode = TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"></local:UCFullName>
    </GroupBox>
    <StackPanel Name="SpBtnInsert" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible">
        <Button Name="btnShowFullName" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2,2,0,0" Background="Transparent" Content="Show Name" Foreground="White" Width="98" Click="BtnShowFullName_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace SomeExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lógica de interacción para MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string PropertyFullName { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnShowFullName_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Current full name :" + PropertyFullName);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Main Window]

And of course, I expected that when I pressed the button, I got a message with the full name entered by the user. However, I got nothing.

[image: Application]

Edit: Here's the solution to the problem, for people who visit this page with a similar problem.

```
<local:UCFullName ValueFullName="{Binding Path = PropertyFullName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"></local:UCFullName>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding to the wrong `AncestorType`. Instead of `UserControl` the type must be `Window`. `Window` extends `Control` but not `UserControl`.

```
<local:UCFullName ValueFullName="{Binding Path=PropertyFullName, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

Also because you set the `Binding.Mode` to `TwoWay`, the binding source `PropertyFullName` must be able to notify the binding target `ValueFullName` about value changes. To achieve this, you need to implement `PropertyFullName` as a `DependencyProperty` to enable two way binding.

As a a side note:
The following code can be problematic

```
public string ValueFullName
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ValueFullNameProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ValueFullNameProperty, value);
        Notify("ValueFullName"); // This line might never get called
    }
}
```

This is just a CLR wrapper for the actual `DependencyProperty` and will never be invoked by the framework. When using the binding on this property the wrapper will never get called and therefore the event will never get raised.

Comment: thank you, that was correct. I only changed the RelativeSource parameter as you said, and remove the TwoWayBinding because I dont really need to use it.

Comment: You are welcome. I added a hint to my answer. The method `Notify("ValueFullName")` might never get called. The binding mechanism or `DependencyProperty` infrastructure doesn't make use of the CLR wrapper. They are just for convenience when accessing the dependency property from code-behind. The framework uses `GetValue` and `SetValue` directly.

Comment: @JulianDavidBautistaOsorio Please note that `Notify("ValueFullName")` is entirely redundant. You don't need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for dependency properties, because they alredady implement their own notification mechanism,

Comment: @BionicCode Thanks for your help. Now I know Notify("ValueFullName") is redundant, and I just removed it and it still works. However, how can I get rid of the wrapper you said it was problematic?

Comment: @JulianDavidBautistaOsorio The wrapper is not the problematic part. I was trying to say what Clemens was saying. The wrapper is bypassed by the framework. Therefore it would become problematic, if you rely on or expect the wrapper setter to be invoked on all property changes. The wrapper itself is not a problem.

Comment: @JulianDavidBautistaOsorio The wrapper lets you access the dependency property like an ordinary property like `this.ValueFullName = "someValue";`. Normally and without this wrapper you would have to access the dependency property via a random `DependencyObject` using `DependencyObject.SetValue` or `DependencyObject.GetValue` like `this.SetValue(ValueFullNameProperty, value);`.

Comment: @JulianDavidBautistaOsorio So, no need to delete the whole wrapper. The `Notify()` is redundant. You don't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on controls at all. `DependencyProperty` is always the preferred choice. It allows to be animated, offers inheritance, allows resources (e.g. `StaticResource`) and more. Functionality you need in views.

Comment: @BionicCode  well and thoroughly explained. thank you so much.

Comment: @JulianDavidBautistaOsorio You are welcome. As a rule, I may add, you should never add any code to the wrapper (except the `SetValue()` and `GetValue()` to delegate the value). If you need something to be done when the dependency property changed then add a [`PropertyChangedCallback Delegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.propertychangedcallback?view=netframework-4.8) to the [`FrameworkPropertyMetadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata?view=netframework-4.8) of the `DependencyProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

As BionicCode has pointed out, you can change the `AncestorType`. Another option is to set `DataContext` of the Window.

You can either do it in the constructor

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = this;
}
```

or in the XAML.

```xml
<Window DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

This way you don't have to specify source in your bindings (as long as you bind to code-behind properties).